# Connecting to remote database server

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, jdbc, jta

I'm developing an application in a container managed environment (Java EE). Therefore, I shouldn't have to worry about handling and closing transactions. I simply inject the EntityManager:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebApplication")
private EntityManager em;
```

And my corresponding `persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="WebApplication" transaction-type="JTA">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://link-to-my-database.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/TestDB"></property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

However, this does not work. According to the [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver` is "attended for use in Java SE environments." (Section 8.2.1.9; page 317). And even the `jta-datasource` and `non-jta-datasource` only "name the data source in the local environment" (Section 8.2.1.5; page 313).

**Then how can I connect to a remote database server?** Obviously, I can explicitly create an EntityManager but then I would be responsible for handling the transactions, then what's the point of being in a container managed environment? If it's possible to connect to a remote database server using JPA and a container managed environment, can you provide an example on how to do so?

Comment: You need to configure your mysql to allow remote connections.

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira The MySQL database is setup for remote connections. I can connect via the MySQL Workbench and Eclipse Datasource Explorer. The problem has to do with connecting in a container managed environment.

Comment: Specify jta-data-source, non-jta-data-source. The data sources can point to a remote database server. You specify the JNDI name on your server.

Comment: You need to set this up in your application server and configure JPA to use the data source which you have created there by providing its JNDI name.

Comment: @NeilStockton @PetrosSplinakis So, the only way to do it is to use `jta-datasource` which specifies the JNDI name to the resource that I must configure through the server administration console? I was afraid of this, considering I'm using a pre-configured environment for deploying my application.